# Launch spring cloud task with JVM args via DeployerPartitionHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-task

I am planning to execute spring batch job on Pivotal cloud Foundry. The job executes fine on a single JVM with multiple threads(Local partitioning). I am looking to scale the job and the first option i considered is running the worker processes as a spring cloud task.

Before run it in PCF i am running it in local. I created a partition handler in the following manner.

```
    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(TaskLauncher taskLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer, TaskRepository taskRepository) throws Exception {
        Resource resource = this.resourceLoader
                .getResource("file:I:/Project/target/batch.jar");

        DeployerPartitionHandler partitionHandler =
                new DeployerPartitionHandler(taskLauncher, jobExplorer, resource, "workerStep", taskRepository);

        List<String> commandLineArgs = new ArrayList<>(3);
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.profiles.active=worker");
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false");
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false");
commandLineArgs.add("--java.security.krb5.conf=I:/krb5.conf");
commandLineArgs.add("--java.security.auth.login.config=I:/jaas.conf");


        partitionHandler
                .setCommandLineArgsProvider(new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs));
        
        partitionHandler
                .setEnvironmentVariablesProvider(new SimpleEnvironmentVariablesProvider(this.environment));
                
        partitionHandler.setMaxWorkers(2);
        partitionHandler.setApplicationName("PartitionedBatchJobTask");

        return partitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("worker")
    public DeployerStepExecutionHandler stepExecutionHandler(JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        return new DeployerStepExecutionHandler(this.context, jobExplorer, this.jobRepository);
    }
```

The task is started, but as mentioned in the args the jar has to run with certain JVM args. These args are not being properly sent to task to start the app as a task. (I am connecting to a DB using Kerberose. Need to send these properties as a JVM arg)

I see the below being executed as a task

```
Command to be executed: I:/java.exe -jar I:/Project/target/batch.jar --spring.profiles.active=worker --spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false --spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false --java.security.krb5.conf=I:/krb5.conf --java.security.auth.login.config=I:/jaas.conf --jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 --spring.cloud.task.job-execution-id=1 --spring.cloud.task.step-execution-id=3 --spring.cloud.task.step-name=workerStep --spring.cloud.task.name=application-1_migrateProfileJob_migrateProfileFollowerStep:partition0 --spring.cloud.task.parentExecutionId=29 --spring.cloud.task.executionid=30
```

Since the JVM args are sent after the jar command the app is not able to recognize th eproperties.. Can any one please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your issue, but your print command is missing a space between `.jar` and `-Dspring...`, see `batch.jar-Ds...` , no space. You also cannot hard code Windows drive names into your path if you expect this to run on CF, which is a Linux environment. You need to generate that path in a platform-agnostic way.

Comment: @DanielMikusa - My Bad, it was a copy paste error. I have updated the description. I understand the location should not be hardcoded, as i am testing in my local pc, i am hard codieng the values. When i deploy in PCF, i shall use the generic location address

Comment: I think you have the kerberos properties set wrong too. They are system properties and system properties are set like `-D<key>=<val>`. You have `"--java.security.krb5.conf=I:/krb5.conf"`

Comment: For the Spring properties, you could pass them through as env variables if that's easier. Boot's flexible configuration can take value from arguments, system properties, or env variables. If arguments are not working as expected, you could use env variables instead. You can also set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='a bunch of arguments you want the JVM to take'` and when the JVM starts it'll load all those settings.